# How should doc comments be spread over multiple elements?

Tags: rust, comments

I need to document a piece of code that is 3-fold. I have an enum element, an associated constructor and a method that uses the enum to do work. Here is a minimal example:

```rust
use regex::{Error, Regex};

pub enum Element {
    And {
        lhs: Box<Element>,
        rhs: Box<Element>,
    },
    Value {
        regex: Regex,
    },
}

impl Element {
    pub fn new_and(lhs: Element, rhs: Element) -> Self {
        Element::And {
            lhs: Box::new(lhs),
            rhs: Box::new(rhs),
        }
    }

    pub fn new_value(regex: &str) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let regex = Regex::new(regex)?;
        Ok(Element::Value { regex })
    }

    pub fn is_match(&self, values: &Vec<String>) -> bool {
        match self {
            Element::And { lhs, rhs } => lhs.is_match(values) && rhs.is_match(values),
            Element::Value { regex } => {
                for value in values {
                    if regex.is_match(value) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                false
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

There definitely needs to be a comment on new_value() to document the possible error. But where should I put information on how the actual element is evaluated?

- Put this also in the comment of new_value() to have all in one place?
- Put it in a comment for Element::Value and is_match() only says that elements are
  evaluated as documented there?
- Put all evaluation information for all enum values in the comment for is_match() and leave Element::Value empty?
- Repeat the evaluation information in all 3 locations?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: A lot of this will come down to personal preference and taste, there's not really any hard and fast rules

That being said, I like to look at the standard library's documentation for inspiration.

Generally, if a function returns a `Result`, some explanation of when it returns an error is probably a good idea. For example: `Returns an error if the regex fails to parse`. You could also look at the docs for `Regex::new` to see what they say about it.

When documenting the behaviour of `is_match`, you should probably put the comment on `is_match`.

But I'd also suggest putting a more comprehensive comment (preferably with a usage example) either in the module (with `//!` at the top) or on `pub enum Element`. Examples are really underrated IMO, and even a simple one can really help a reader to understand the purpose of this type.

For example, the docs for `String` (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) have quite a lot of detail on various uses of `String` as doc comments on the `String` struct itself.